# Div's gradient background transition without it becoming transparent

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

I'm making a js player and I have html containers representing songs. Inside this containers I also have menu appended. On click song's container has `selected` class added to it's classList, changing color of `background` (not `background-color`) with transition. 
The problem is that on click div becomes transparent (loses its old background property for a moment I suppose) and then transitions to a new background color. It makes the upper edge of menu visible during transition.
I wanted to know is there a way to have background changed without this moment of transparency.

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8d12hu3r/14/

```js
container = document.getElementById('songContainer');
container.addEventListener('click', function() {
  container.classList.add('selected');
});
```

```css
#songContainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgb(223, 228, 248), rgb(223, 228, 248), rgb(223, 228, 248));
  /*background: rgb(223, 228, 248);*/
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  transition-duration: 5s;
}

.selected {
  color: white;
  background: #2b3492 !important;
  transition: 5s;
}

#menuBump {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

#songMenu {
  border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
  /*display: table;*/
  min-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  /*bottom: 0px;*/
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  z-index: 10;
  background: #fff1e3;
}

.songMenu-item {
  background: inherit;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  transition-duration: 5s;
}

.songMenu-item:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
  background: #ac4d8f;
}
```

```html
<div id="song-menu-container" style="position: relative; height: 20px;">
  <div id="songContainer" style="z-index: 10000">Gehou</div>
  <div id="menuBump">
    <div id="songMenu">
      <div class="songMenu-item" data-id="2">Nise</div>
      <div class="songMenu-item" data-id="5">asdf</div>
      <div class="songMenu-item" data-id="8">zcdaaassdasd</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I did also try changing background property itself with js, but the result is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are using `background` and not `background-color`. More specifically:

1. `background` is a shorthand for multiple properties. The liner gradient you are using is a `background-image` while the solid color you're transitioning to is a `background-color`. So you're transitioning two different things, which won't work.
2. Even if you tried to transition to a different linear gradient, it still wouldn't work because you simply can't transition gradients.

Fortunately the solution in your case is very simple: the linear gradient you are using isn't actually a gradient at all – it's the same color all the way across – so you can just replace it with a background color and then everything will work fine. The commented-out code you have right below the gradient is exactly what you want.

If you were trying to find out how to transition a gradient, since you can't do that directly, you'd have to do a more elaborate workaround. For example, you could overlay a semi-transparent color on a gradient to mimic the look you want, then transition that overlay so it completely covers the gradient below it.

Comment: This is your answer. If you end up needing to transition a color on top of the gradient for some reason, another possibility would be to use a pseudo-element with a background color.

Comment: yeah, I know this gradient isn't really a gradient, I messed up a little, there is a gradient in the project (-webkit-linear-gradient(left, #7F7FD5, #86A8E7, rgb(145, 201, 234))), just forgot to switch that back, so the idea is to change that gradient to plain color, sorry for confusion. I thought about some overlay, just wanted to make sure there is no way to do that easier. I guess I will stick to that, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
@keyframes example {
  from {opacity: 0.5;}
  to {opacity: 1;}
}


#songContainer {
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 4s;
}
```

i think this can give you an idea of what you can do